# Использование png картинок со шрифтом в Unity

Tags: unity3d, шрифты

Нахожу множество бесплатных шрифтов, которые выложены просто картинкой в формате png, как я могу использовать эти шрифты в юнити? Может есть способ создания шрифта формата ttf, используя картинку?

Comment: Никак. png - растровый формат. А шрифты в векторе.

Comment: @Suviturf есть фокусы при помощи sdf с этим, но боюсь вопрос не про это https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/valve/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_AlphaTestedMagnification.pdf

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=slvRsAYS7zw

Comment: @Suvitruf Почему тогда я так часто встречаю что люди выкладываю шрифты(в основном пиксельные) в формате png? Видимо, есть способ как то преобразовать эту картинку в шрифт.

Comment: ну да, сложить их в hashtable и брать по ключу

Comment: @VladislavSit в шрифт никто ничего не преобразует. Они просто спрайтам рисуют текст.

Comment: @Stranger in the Q  "ну да, сложить их в hashtable и брать по ключу" Как это реализовать?  Я не знаю как это гуглить даже

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/creating-a-custom-font-from-an-image.422297/

Comment: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/sprite-font-builder-37343